# How to bind VSCode Docker extension into Minikube's Docker?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, minikube, vscode-remote

I want to use Visual-Studio-Code to bind onto a container, that is running on the Docker instance inside Minikube.

The Docker extension by default binds to the Docker instance running on localhost, rather than then Docker instance running inside minikube.

In a shell I'd just do:

```
eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

so my `docker ..` commands would execute inside Minikube.

But how can I tell VSCode to pre-run the docker-env command?
Or how can I tell VSCode where the Minikube Docker instance is? I don't seem to find any setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available called `Bridge to Kubernetes` using this plugin you can iteratively run and debug containers directly in MiniKube, Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), or another Kubernetes provider, you have to [install](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mindaro.mindaro) this plugin and make necessary [configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/overview-bridge-to-kubernetes) for playing with your containers on minikube.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup environment variables, that are set by `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)` using `Docker: Environment` setting in the VSCode
[example on the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41d0R.png)

To determine which environment variables were set you can run command to view all the environment variables before `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)`  and after.

If you use zsh terminal you can do it using `printenv` command.